# Почему не происходит проверка на цену биткоина?

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть файл bot.py

```
import logging
from typing import Text
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import config
import requests
import json
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text

def get_bitcoin_price() -> int:
    # Делаем запрос на получение цены биткоина
    response = requests.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd').text
    bitcoinjson = json.loads(response)
    return int(bitcoinjson["bitcoin"]["usd"])


# Объект бота
bot = Bot(config.token)

# Диспетчер для бота
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Включаем логирование, чтобы не пропустить важные сообщения
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Хэндлер на команду /price
@dp.message_handler(commands=["price"])
async def priceb(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f"Цена биткоина = {get_bitcoin_price()}")

@dp.message_handler(commands=["alert"])   
async def alarm(message: types.Message):
    mean = message.text[6:]
    if int(mean) == int(get_bitcoin_price()):
       await message.answer(f'Биткоин пересёк отметку {mean}$')
    if int(mean) > int(get_bitcoin_price()):
        if int(mean) < int(get_bitcoin_price()):
            await message.answer(f'Биткоин пересёк отметку {mean}$')
    else:  
        if int(mean) > int(get_bitcoin_price()):
            await message.answer(f'Биткоин пересёк отметку {mean}$')       

    



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Запуск бота
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

В декораторе есть значение mean - это значение которое указывает пользователь для оповещения. В команде /alert просходит проверка на то что если mean > цены биткоина то когда mean < цена биткоина должно написать в чат (f'Биткоин пересёк отметку {mean}$'), но этого не происходит. Бот просто ничего не пишет.

Comment: А вы проверьте ветки условий, у вас только при строгом равенстве может что-то напечататься, а дальше у вас взаимоисключающие условия стоят, там контроль до `await message.answer` никогда не дойдёт, разберитесь с условиями. Сейчас чтобы это сработало цена должна быть **одновременно и больше и меньше**, чем `mean`.

Comment: спасибо понял ошибку